# What finite groups always have a cube root for each element?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am generalizing my question here [about square roots in groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728124/what-finite-groups-always-have-a-square-root-for-each-element).

If I have a group $G$ with $|G|= 0 \mod 3$, then the map $f(x) = x^3$ is not one-to-one, and hence a cube root doesn't always exist.

If $|G|  = 2 \mod 3$, then I can find the cube root of $g \in G$ by computing $g^{1/3} = g^{(|G|+1)/3}$.

The last case to consider is if $|G| = 1 \mod 3$. The previous technique will not work, but we can find for $g \in G$ an element $g^{2/3}$ such that $(g^{2/3})^3=g^2$ by choosing $g^{2/3} = g^{(|G|+2)/3}$.

If we also have $|G| = 1 \mod 2$, then by the previous question we can take a square root and hence get a cube root for each element. But what if $|G|=0 \mod 2$? Can we still always get a cube root?

Comment: I think I have a proposed way of working this out, but I hope people don't mind me setting the stage for my next question about finding fifth roots, where my idea doesn't work and I am not sure how to resolve.

Comment: See my answer to your previous problem. It generalises easily to "each element of a finite group is a $p$-th power (with $p$ prime) iff $p$ is not a factor of $|G|$".

Comment: Yes, I just realized that $x |G| = -1 \mod p$ is solvable for $x$ when $\gcd(|G|,p)=1$. Thus, we can always take $g^{(x|G|+1)/p}$ as our $p$th root.

Comment: Alternatively, a $p$th root exists iff $f(x)=x^p$ is one-to-one. The function $f$ is one-to-one iff $(ab^{-1})^p = 1$ implies that $a=b$. Thus $f$ is one-to-one iff $x^p=1$ has the unique solution $x=1$. This is not true when $|G|=np$. This is true when $|G|=np+r$, $0 < r < p$.

Comment: You maybe can ask such a question for every prime $p$. Or, better, consider all primes altogether, since the argument is the same. Exercise ($n\ge 1$, $G$ finite group): show the equivalences ($x\mapsto x^n$ is bijective in $G$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($x\mapsto x^n$ is surjective in $G$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($x\mapsto x^n$ is injective in $G$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($n$ is coprime to $|G|$).

Answer (score 4):

Sure we can. If $|G|=1\mod 3$, then $g^{(2|G|+1)/3}$ is a cube root of $g$ for every $g\in G$.

This generalizes to $n$th roots. If $|G|=k\mod n$ and $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, then let $r$ be $k^{-1}\mod n$, so that $rk=1\mod n$. Then $g^{(-rk+1)/n}$ is an $n$th root of $g$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: Ah, this actually answer my question for fifth roots as well. Thanks!