# Finite group of odd order with elements that are square

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The problem I am struggling with is

"Find an example of a finite group G of order n where n is odd and each element of G is a square".

In my understanding this means

"Find a finite group with odd number of elements where each element can be expressed in ( )^2 form".

Am I understanding the question incorrectly?

I can't seem to find any finite group that fits this criteria.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. What's the simplest group you can think of? Does it work?

Comment: The trivial group satisfies this.

Comment: Did you actually manage to find a group that did not fit the criteria?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728124/what-finite-groups-always-have-a-square-root-for-each-element

Comment: See also this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522273/if-a-group-g-has-odd-order-then-the-square-function-is-injective).

Comment: $\{0\}$ has order 1 and $0 = 0^2$.  $\mathbb Z_7$ has order $7$ and $0 = 0^2$, $1 = 4^2$, $2 = 1^2$, $3 = 5^2$, and $4 = 2^2$ , $5=6^2$ and $6 = 3^2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $|G| = n$ then for any $g\in G$, $g^n = e$.  So $g^{n+ 1} = g$ and $g= (g^{\frac {n+1}2})^2$ is a square.

So *all* groups with odd order satisfy this condition.

So you couldn't find any groups that *failed* the condition.  You just didn't realize how they satisfied it.

....

(One thing to note.  If the operation is "$*$" then a square is a number $m = x*x$.  So if the operation is addition a "square" is a number $m = x + x$.  So for, say, $\mathbb Z_5, +$ $0 = 0+0; 1 = 3+3; 2=1+1; 3=4+4; 4=2+2$ are all squares.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ G $ be a finite group of odd order. Let $ \phi: G \to G $ via $ x \mapsto x^2 $. Then we claim $ \phi $ is an injection.

Let $ |G| = n $. Suppose $ x^2 = y^2 $. $ x = x^{n + 1} $. Then $ n + 1 $ is even, so let $ n + 1 = 2k $. Similarly, $ y = y^{2k} $. Then $ x = x^{2k} = y^{2k} = y $. Thus $ \phi $ is an injection. As $ G $ is finite, it is therefore a surjection, so every element of $ G $ is a square. Thus, *all* groups of odd order satisfy this.

Comment: See my comment above...